# Why I can't center the footer of a PDF with ITEXT pdf 7?

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext7

I'm trying to build a pdf generator and I must add 2 different footers based on the tipe of file im generating.
One has just a text that says "This PDF is a sample".
The other one is basically a 3 columns table with a short description and 2 logos.

The problem is that the style of both the table and text gets overwritten somehow once i invoke the event handler, and i can't center both footers to the table.

The table has even more problems than the text because it's width gets reduced and so there is no spacing between the logos and the text

I also noticed that the position of the footer depends on how many pages i have

for example this is how the footer looks like most of the times (the position is not always the same, and never the right position):
[image]

I tried setting the horizontal alignement to all the object

This is one of my cells, the others are identical except for the content

```
 Image trustedImage = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(pathLogo3));
        trustedImage.scaleToFit(100, 100);

        Cell trustedIdentity = new Cell().setBorder(new SolidBorder(whiteColor, 1f));
        trustedIdentity.add(trustedImage.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER));
        table.addCell(trustedIdentity.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE));
```

As you can see i setted the horizontal alignment to both the image and the cell

This is how I invoke the eventHandler
               `pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new TableFooterEventHandler(creaTabellaFineDocumentoPlaceholder()));`

and this is the actual TableFooterEventHandler class

````
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.Event;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.IEventHandler;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.events.PdfDocumentEvent;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Canvas;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.HorizontalAlignment;

public class TableFooterEventHandler implements IEventHandler {

    private Table table;
    public TableFooterEventHandler(Table table) {
        this.table=table;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamBefore(), page.getResources(), pdfDoc);

        float tableHeight = table.getHeight() == null ? 30  :  table.getHeight().getValue();
        float tableWidth = table.getWidth() == null ? 30  :  table.getWidth().getValue();


        float x = (page.getPageSize().getWidth() - table.getWidth().getValue()) /2;

        new Canvas(canvas, new Rectangle(x, 20, table.getWidth().getValue(), 30))
                .add(table.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
                .close();
    }
}```

As you can see here I'm creating a `Canvas` containing a `Rectangle` containing the `Table`

I followed and example from ITEXT itself on this page (the first example) : [text](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/page-events-for-headers-and-footers)
And except for the "style" of the footer it kinda works 


somebody know why it does't center the footer and it also overwrites the table settings, and how should I fix it?
````

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The rectangle i was creating was wrong.
It was as big as the table, so evrything was shrinking.
I set his dimentions to the width of the Document and the height of the table

like this:

```
new Canvas(canvas, new Rectangle(30, 40,documentWidth , tableHeight))
            .add(table).close();
}
```

Now it's centered and not distorted